# Regex: Split characters with "/"

Tags: python, regex

I have these strings, for example:
`['2300LO/LCE','2302KO/KCE']`

I want to have output like this:
`['2300LO','2300LCE','2302KO','2302KCE']`

How can I do it with Regex in Python?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a simple generator that yields the pairs for each string. Then you can flatten them into a single list with `itertools.chain()`

```
from itertools import product, chain

def getCombos(s):
    nums, code = re.match(r'(\d+)(.*)', s).groups()
    for pair in product([nums], code.split("/")):
        yield ''.join(pair) 

a = ['2300LO/LCE','2302KO/KCE']

list(chain.from_iterable(map(getCombos, a)))
# ['2300LO', '2300LCE', '2302KO', '2302KCE']
```

This has the added side benefit or working with strings like `'2300LO/LCE/XX/CC'` which will give you `['2300LO', '2300LCE', '2300XX', '2300CC',...]`

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
list1 = ['2300LO/LCE','2302KO/KCE']
list2 = []

for x in list1:        
    a = x.split('/')

    tmp = re.findall(r'\d+', a[0]) # extracting digits
    list2.append(a[0])
    list2.append(tmp[0] + a[1])

print(list2)
```

Comment: This will give you an `IndexError`. `tmp` is a single element list.

Answer (score 1):

This can be implemented with simple string splits.

Since you asked the output with regex, here is your answer.

```
list1 = ['2300LO/LCE','2302KO/KCE']

import re
r = re.compile("([0-9]{1,4})([a-zA-Z].*)/([a-zA-Z].*)")
out = []
for s in list1:
  items = r.findall(s)[0]
  out.append(items[0]+items[1])
  out.append(items[2])

print(out)
```

The explanation for the regex  - (4 digit number), followed by (any characters), followed by a / and (rest of the characters).

they are grouped with () , so that when you use find all, it becomes individual elements.